# I want to fetch a exact match record from db using jpa but it is giving multiple record

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa

// jpa repository code to crud operation

@Query(value = "select * from flatdetails fd inner join  vehicledetail veh  on fd.flatdetailsid = veh.flatDetailsId where veh.registrationNumber like %?1% and fd.tenantId =?2", nativeQuery = true)
List findByRegistrationNumberAndTenantTenantid(String registrationNumber,long tenantid);

// service implementation layer code
flatDetilsList = flatDetailsRepository.findByRegistrationNumberAndTenantTenantid(vehicleParkingDetailsDto.getVehicleNumber(),vehicleParkingDetailsDto.getTenantId());
}

```
        flatDetilsList.stream().forEach(fd -> {
            List<VehicleDto> vehicleDtoList = new ArrayList();
            VehicleParkingResponseDto dto = new VehicleParkingResponseDto();
            List<VehicleDetail> list = fd.getVehicleDetails();
            list.stream().forEach(ve -> {
                VehicleDto vecDto = new VehicleDto();
                vecDto.setVehicleDetailId(ve.getVehicleDetailId());
                vecDto.setRegistrationNumber(ve.getRegistrationNumber());
                vecDto.setVehicleOwnerName(ve.getVehicleOwnerName());
                vecDto.setVehicleTypeValue(ve.getVehicleType().getValue());
                vecDto.setParkingTypeValue(ve.getParkingType().getValue());
                vecDto.setParkingSlotValue(ve.getParkingSlot().getValue());

                vehicleDtoList.add(vecDto);
            });
            dto.setFlatDetailsId(fd.getFlatdetailsid());
            dto.setFlatNo(fd.getFlatno());
            dto.setVehiclList(vehicleDtoList);
            vehicleParkingTempList.add(dto);
        });


    } catch (Exception e) 
    {

    }
    return vehicleParkingTempList;
```

Answer (score 0):

There can be a possible mistake made by query side since you have used vehiclereg_no like -> this generates all the reg no that matches the matcher value you are going to provide and if you want only one single record to be returned then you can try using limit.

Use the query in this way, given below

```
@Query(value = "select * from flatdetails fd inner join vehicledetail veh on fd.flatdetailsid = veh.flatDetailsId where veh.registrationNumber = ?1 and fd.tenantId =?2", nativeQuery = true) List findByRegistrationNumberAndTenantTenantid(String registrationNumber,long tenantid) limit 1;
```

Comment: again the same issue is coming